# Yield Curve package R

Tags: r

I want to interpolate a yield curve using Nelson-Siegel model. I'm new to R language but decided to use the "Yield Curve" package (available here http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/YieldCurve/index.html and documentation's link: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/YieldCurve/YieldCurve.pdf) There are 2 problems I faced:

1) I don't understand why the first 2 parameters of NSrates in the 6th and 7th line of the following code(p.6 in documentation) took that format:

```
data(FedYieldCurve)
tau <- c(3, 6, 12, 60, 84, 120)
mediumTerm <- c(12,60,84)
NSParameters <- Nelson.Siegel(rate=FedYieldCurve[1:10,],
                              maturity=tau, MidTau=mediumTerm )
y <- NSrates(NSParameters[5,1:3],
             NSParameters$lambda[5],tau)
plot(tau,FedYieldCurve[5,],main="Fitting Nelson-Siegel yield curve", type="o")
lines(tau,y, col=2)
legend("topleft",legend=c("observed yield curve","fitted yield curve"),
col=c(1,2),lty=1)
grid()
```

2) how to extract a certain yield from the curve? For example, If I have a maturity of 12 months, what is its related yield?.

Thank you a lot for taking time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the help page for `NSrates`.

It takes 3 arguments:

> betaCoeff: vector or matrix of the beta's coefficients.
>
> lambdat: value of the estimated lambda
>
> maturity: maturity of the yield curve of which want to return the interest rates.

For `betaCeff`, the code you show uses `NSParameters[5, 1:3]`, or

```
   beta_0    beta_1   beta_2
5 13.7156 -1.468064 1.237194
```

which is a `data.frame`.  Although `data.frame` is not explicitly stated as a possible input, the first line of the function converts it to a `matrix` (assuming you're using the CRAN version)

```
if(is.vector(betaCoeff)) betaCoeff <- matrix( betaCoeff, 1, 3)
```

For `lambdat`, the code you show uses `NSParameters$lambda[5]` which is the `numeric` value to use for the estimated lambda.

The final argument is `maturity`.  The code you showed uses `tau` which is

```
> tau
[1]   3   6  12  60  84 120
```

Per the documentation, the function will

> Return interest rates in matrix object with number of rows equal to nrow(betaCoeff) and number of columns equal to length(maturity).

In this case, you get

```
> y
           3        6       12      60       84      120
[1,] 12.7394 13.05852 13.40245 13.6897 13.69721 13.70273
```

If you only want the 12 month `maturity`, then pass only `12` to the `maturity` argument.

```
> NSrates(NSParameters[5,1:3], NSParameters$lambda[5], 12)
           12
[1,] 13.40245
```

Comment: So in `NSParameters[5, 1:3]` we basically want the values of the 3 beta coefficients , but what does the first index ( [5, ) in it refers to? And for `NSParameters$lambda[5]` I understand from your answer that it is the value of lambda, but I don't understand what the input `x` in `NSParameters$lambda[x]` means.

Comment: `NSParameters` is a `data.frame` with 10 rows.  `NSParameters[5, ]` means to only use the 5th row of the data.frame.  `lambda` is a column in the `NSParameters` `data.frame`.  So, `NSParameters$lamda` is a vector of 10 values.  `NSParameters$lamda[5]` is only the 5th element of that vector and is equivalent to `NSParameters[5, "lambda"]`.  See [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) for info on basic subsetting.

Comment: Thank you for answering GSee. I have no problems understanding subsetting of data here. The problem is that I don't know what do the rows and columns refer to. For instance, the author used here `FedYieldCurve[1:10,]`, but what does the `[x,y]` component represent in it? Does x mean yields and y maturities?  Same thing for `NSParameters[5,1:3]`, it's visible that `,1:3]` mean that we choose the first three columns of the data frame but what about the `[5,` ? Why choose the 5th line? And what does it represent? I searched a lot about this problem but unfortunateIy I have got no results.

Comment: Type `FedYieldCurve` and hit enter and I think you will be able to tell that "x" is the month and "y" is rates at various maturities; each row is an observation of the yield curve at a point in time.  I can't say for sure why the author chose the 5th observation of the yield curve, but I think it was probably just chosen arbitrarily for the example.